# Finding most frequently occurring string in a structure in Rust?

Tags: rust, iterator

I'm looking for the string which occurs most frequently in the second part of the tuple of `Vec<(String, Vec<String>)>`:

```
use itertools::Itertools; // 0.8.0

fn main() {
    let edges: Vec<(String, Vec<String>)> = vec![];

    let x = edges
        .iter()
        .flat_map(|x| &x.1)
        .map(|x| &x[..])
        .sorted()
        .group_by(|x| x)
        .max_by_key(|x| x.len());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a1fa8cb8a8cc334e594d2b3eb5da3e92)

This:

- takes the iterator
- flat-maps to the second part of the tuple
- turns elements into a `&str`
- sorts it (via itertools)
- groups it by string (via itertools)
- find the group with the highest count

This supposedly gives me the group with the most frequently occurring string, except it doesn't compile:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `max_by_key` found for type `itertools::groupbylazy::GroupBy<&&str, std::vec::IntoIter<&str>, [closure@src/lib.rs:9:19: 9:24]>` in the current scope
  --> src/lib.rs:10:10
   |
10 |         .max_by_key(|x| x.len());
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: the method `max_by_key` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `&mut itertools::groupbylazy::GroupBy<&&str, std::vec::IntoIter<&str>, [closure@src/lib.rs:9:19: 9:24]> : std::iter::Iterator`
```

I'm totally lost in these types.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You didn't read [the documentation for a function you are using](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.group_by). This is *not* a good idea.

> This type implements `IntoIterator` (it is **not** an iterator itself),
>   because the group iterators need to borrow from this value. It should
>   be stored in a local variable or temporary and iterated.

---

Personally, I'd just use a `BTreeMap` or `HashMap`:

```
let mut counts = BTreeMap::new();
for word in edges.iter().flat_map(|x| &x.1) {
    *counts.entry(word).or_insert(0) += 1;
}

let max = counts.into_iter().max_by_key(|&(_, count)| count);

println!("{:?}", max);
```

If you *really* wanted to use the iterators, it could look something like this:

```
let groups = edges
    .iter()
    .flat_map(|x| &x.1)
    .sorted()
    .group_by(|&x| x);

let max = groups
    .into_iter()
    .map(|(key, group)| (key, group.count()))
    .max_by_key(|&(_, count)| count);
```

Comment: Yes, you got me. I came from functional languages where iterators didn't have nearly this level of noise. But, Rust has many niceties to balance out, so I'm still hanging in there.